# Mysql search table w/ php and return results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make my search look in my database for $searchtext where $selecteditem represents the columb it's searching. Im getting syntax errors around the last part of the code

My form-

```
<form name="search" id="search" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm" id="searchterm">
    <select name="selectitem">
        <option value="propertydescription">Property/Description</option>
        <option value="transactiontype">Transaction type</option>
        <option value="applicabledocument">Applicable document</option>
        <option value="recieved">recieved</option>
        <option value="paid">paid</option>
    </select>

</div></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="search" value="search"></td>
```

My php for this-

```
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $columbname = $_POST['selectitem'];
    $searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND WHERE '$columbname' = '$searchterm'";
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
else
```

Comment: You don't need `AND WHERE`,  you should just use `AND`

Comment: Your php code is incomplete. Also you are open to sql injections. Read up about prepared statements.

Comment: Inevitable sermon: Sanitize user input, don't use die(mysql_error()) on production system.

Comment: do not use mysql_ extension it's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove second `WHERE`
2. Remove quotes around the column name that you get from `$columbname` variable.

Change

```
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND WHERE '$columbname' = '$searchterm'";
```

to

```
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname = '$searchterm'";
```

*On a side note: your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. Switch to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements.*

Comment: That gets rid of the error but now the search is not working :/

Answer (score 5):

```
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
$columbname = $_POST['selectitem'];
$searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname = '$searchterm'";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have replace your `PHP` code, and now it's working well

```
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
$columbname = $_POST['selectitem'];
$searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' && 'columbname' = '$searchterm'";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
else
```

Answer (score 4):

Please replace the  `AND WHERE` by just `AND` in your SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

Use this (Delete the second where):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' 
AND '$columbname' = '$searchterm'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix the query. Use this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND '$columbname' = '$searchterm'"
```

Instead of:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND WHERE '$columbname' = '$searchterm'"
```

(you have one too many *WHERE*)

Answer (score 3):

you should replace the `AND WHERE` by `AND` in you `SELECT` query and no need of `'` in `$columbname`

```
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
 $columbname  = $_POST['selectitem'];
 $searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];
 $query       = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE (agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname = '$searchterm')";
 $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

> Note: do not use [mysql_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) extension it's deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php)
>   or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM transactions 
          WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' 
          AND $columbname = '$searchterm'";
```